# Gridview with access data source will not update or delete asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've looked all over, studied books, tutorial videos and numerous articles, and I can't solve this problem. Within visual studio 2010 insert a gridview, I specify the data source as a access database. Within the specification I include the option to insert, update and delete records. The gridview appears on the screen, and when I test the webpage it loads up with the relevant buttons for updating and inserting etc. 
When testing the page, I click the update button, alter a row and then click update. The page goes back to how it was previously, the record remains the same. I refresh the page to make certain its not updated, and it definitely hasn't. 
I've followed tutorials exactly, and can't get the fields to update or delete when using this method. The database im using is an access one, an mdb file.

I'm sure im missing something massively simple here, but im not sure what. If anyone could offer some help I'd be very grateful! thanks

Here is my code for the form.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Book Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
                ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Book Id" HeaderText="Book Id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Book Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ISBN Number" HeaderText="ISBN Number" 
                SortExpression="ISBN Number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Author" HeaderText="Author" 
                SortExpression="Author" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Publisher" HeaderText="Publisher" 
                SortExpression="Publisher" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date Published" HeaderText="Date Published" 
                SortExpression="Date Published" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Availability" HeaderText="Availability" 
                SortExpression="Availability" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:booksellerConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblBooks] WHERE [Book Id] = ? AND (([ISBN Number] = ?) OR ([ISBN Number] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Title] = ?) OR ([Title] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Author] = ?) OR ([Author] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Publisher] = ?) OR ([Publisher] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Date Published] = ?) OR ([Date Published] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND [Availability] = ? AND (([Price] = ?) OR ([Price] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblBooks] ([Book Id], [ISBN Number], [Title], [Author], [Publisher], [Date Published], [Availability], [Price]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:booksellerConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblBooks]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblBooks] SET [ISBN Number] = ?, [Title] = ?, [Author] = ?, [Publisher] = ?, [Date Published] = ?, [Availability] = ?, [Price] = ? WHERE [Book Id] = ? AND (([ISBN Number] = ?) OR ([ISBN Number] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Title] = ?) OR ([Title] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Author] = ?) OR ([Author] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Publisher] = ?) OR ([Publisher] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Date Published] = ?) OR ([Date Published] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND [Availability] = ? AND (([Price] = ?) OR ([Price] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Book_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ISBN_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ISBN_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Publisher" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Publisher" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Date_Published" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Date_Published" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Availability" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Decimal" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Book_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ISBN_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Publisher" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Published" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Availability" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ISBN_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Publisher" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Published" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Availability" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Book_Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ISBN_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ISBN_Number" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Title" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Author" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Publisher" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Publisher" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Date_Published" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Date_Published" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Availability" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Price" Type="Decimal" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

asp.cs file below;

```
namespace Second
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, could you also share the code-behind file for your page (the aspx.cs file)? **PS** I have re-tagged your question as "asp.net" rather than "classic asp" to make the tag correct and so that hopefully the right people can help you out

Comment: Hello! My asp.cs file is blank, more or less - just contains the default code
... It's been edited in above. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, your .cs is blank? How are you handling the OnClick events for your buttons? Where does the data binding take place? (Maybe I'm missing something, too.)

Comment: It's all handled within the gridview. I clicked on the tooltip for the gridview in designer view  and selected "enable editing" and "enable deletion" This then placed the two buttons onto the gridview control in a separate column, my understanding was the wizard generated all the relevant code from there. When I click the edit button when testing the webpage, the dialog responds to the click so there is some click event happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't necessarily have a straight answer, but some suggestions:

It might be because of the complexity of your `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE [tblBooks] SET [ISBN Number] = ?, [Title] = ?, [Author] = ?, [Publisher] = ?, [Date Published] = ?, [Availability] = ?, [Price] = ? WHERE [Book Id] = ? AND (([ISBN Number] = ?) OR ([ISBN Number] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Title] = ?) OR ([Title] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Author] = ?) OR ([Author] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Publisher] = ?) OR ([Publisher] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND (([Date Published] = ?) OR ([Date Published] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL)) AND [Availability] = ? AND (([Price] = ?) OR ([Price] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))
```

Because you've got quite a hefty `WHERE` clause. If you just pared it back to:

```
UPDATE [tblBooks] SET [ISBN Number] = ?, [Title] = ?, [Author] = ?, [Publisher] = ?, [Date Published] = ?, [Availability] = ?, [Price] = ? WHERE [Book Id] = ?
```

And trimmed back your `<UpdateParameters>` accordingly, does that have any effect?

Also (and it's been a little while for me) I noticed that your parameter names (e.g. `Book_Id`) do not match exactly the data field bindings (e.g. `Book Id`) so that might be causing an issue. I believe that they need to match up (or it is good that they do) for [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228051%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) purposes but in this case they don't.

It might be worth modifying your database so that the column names are things like [Book_Id], [ISBN_Number] etc...I think it is quite rare to have spaces in database column (certainly rare from my experience...but I am not that experienced!)

Comment: I think you might be onto something with the databindings and the spaces. I did manage to insert values into the table using a detailsview control while troubleshooting earlier. I entered values for all fields and chose insert. When I inserted it added a record which contained all fields apart from the ibsn number and the date published, which as you've indicated have a space on them... Think you may have solved it! I'll get back to you shortly! Thanks!

Comment: you were right with the spaces in the field titles - I corrected these in access, updating and deleting now works. The "tortured" setup for the update statement was inserted by visual studio, I agree it seems odd it has so many clauses - somewhat confusing to someone just starting out! Anyhow you have my gratitude, and have saved me from pulling out all of my hair. Thank-you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, try removing the line
`ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"`.  Will the update occur now?